# How are @interface, @implementation & program sections organised (in files) in an objective-c program?

Tags: objective-c

What is an ideal way to organise Following program:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    // ---- @interface section ----

    @interface Fraction: NSObject

    -(void) print;
    -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
    -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

    @end

    // --- @implementation section ---

    @implementation Fraction
    {
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    }

    -(void) print
    {
        NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator,denominator);
    }

    -(void) setNumerator:(int)n
    {
        numerator = n;
    }

    -(void) setDenominator:(int)d
    {
        denominator = d;
    }

    @end

    // -- Program section --

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {

            Fraction *frac1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
            Fraction *frac2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];

            [frac1 setNumerator: 2];
            [frac1 setDenominator: 3];

            [frac1 print];

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I am asking this noob question as in X-Code there is a provision to have your classes separately and the book I am learning from (Programming with objective-C) does not specify where to put which block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective c

- .h : header File,define  ,declare variable methods etc
- .m : implementation file ,all method implementation takes place here
- .xib : nib file for the Interface builder file for the view
  management part
- storyboard : advanced form of nib where all nibs in a
  single file as different scene
- .h   @interface definintion of the file and .m  @implementation
- main.m starting point of the code logic .

The different file scheme is not necessarly needed for the proper working ,a single file with all these can do the job

Answer (score 0):

The @inteface sections goes into a .h file. the @implementation goes into a .m file.

This is probably explained in the book, although for convenience listings are usually given in one piece.

Answer (score 0):

Interface declarations belong in the header-file (*.h).

Implementation declerations belong in the implementation-file (*.m).

You can add interface declarations to your implementation-file, but this will be private declarations.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ---- @interface section ----

    @interface Fraction: NSObject

    -(void) print;
    -(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
    -(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

    @end
```

Goes into a class header file.

```
// --- @implementation section ---

@implementation Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator,denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator:(int)d
{
    denominator = d;
}

@end
```

Goes into class implementation file

```
// -- Program section --

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Fraction *frac1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
        Fraction *frac2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        [frac1 setNumerator: 2];
        [frac1 setDenominator: 3];

        [frac1 print];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Goes into main.m

My suggestion in your project, add a new file, which of type Objective-C class. Then in your header file, copy the header file code and in your implementation, copy the implementation file code. Then in your main.m, just import the header file for your code to work...